# Java socket write error when client disconnects from server

Tags: java, sockets, javafx, client-server

I am working on a chat app in Java and so far everything works all right except that when a client disconnects and a message is send by other client this error pops out:

```
  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:401)
    at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:323)
    at com.terkea/com.terkea.system.server.ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

This is my server Thread:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        while (!socket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                    String input = in.readUTF();
                    if (Message.fromJSON(input).getUserName().equals("REGISTER")) {
                        Message specialMessage = Message.fromJSON(input);
                        specialMessage.setUserName("SERVER");

                        Client test = Client.fromJSON(specialMessage.getMessage());
                        test.setIp(socket.getInetAddress().toString());
                        test.setListening_port(String.valueOf(socket.getPort()));
                        specialMessage.setMessage(Client.toJSON(test));

                        input = Message.toJSON(specialMessage);

                    }
                    for (ClientThread thatClient : server.getClients()) {
                        DataOutputStream outputParticularClient = new DataOutputStream(thatClient.getSocket().getOutputStream());
                        outputParticularClient.writeUTF(input);
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the Client:

```
public void createClient() {

    try {
        socket = new Socket(getHost(), portNumber);

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        Message registerclient = new Message("REGISTER", Client.toJSON(getClient()));
        out.writeUTF(Message.toJSON(registerclient));

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (!socket.isClosed()) {
                try {
                    if (in.available() > 0) {
                        String input = in.readUTF();
                        Message inputMessage = Message.fromJSON(input);
                        if (inputMessage.getUserName().equals("SERVER")) {
                            System.err.println(Client.fromJSON(inputMessage.getMessage()));
                            allClientsConnected.add(Client.fromJSON(inputMessage.getMessage()));
                        } else {
                            chat.add(inputMessage);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error corresponds to `outputParticularClient.writeUTF(input);`

My goal is to get rid of this error and also if possible could anybody tell me a way to check when a client disconnects? I've found some similar questions over here and their solution was to check `if (socket.getInputStream().read()!=-1)`
but when I do that the whole program freezes and the GUI stops working.

Comment: Did you try 
    `catch(SocketException se){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`?

Comment: I just did and the error is the same.

Comment: You get that error because you are writing to a closed socket. Architecting a more elegant solution is probably beyond the scope of this question, but it's not the end of the world to simply try the write and catch the exception, then close the socket yourself.

Comment: `socket.isClosed()` does not do what you think it does. In particular, it doesn't tell you if the peer has closed the socket.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into expanding upon your special message functionality, and instead of using the username to pass "REGISTER" use something like `messageType` in order to do so.  This way you can configure handlers based on type to do a number of things. For example things like:

```
MessageType { REGISTER, UNREGISTER, READ_RECEIPT, ... }
```

You can then have things like:

```
RegisterHandler {}
UnregisterHandler{}
```

and eventually expand them to have some features like facebook/whatsapp (/ICQ haha):

```
TypingHandler {} // Other user gets a message saying that I am typing to them
```

From here, you can implement the UNREGISTER to do what you want.  Like the first comment says, you should catch the SocketException and manually unregister that client so it doesn't happen anymore.  But you should also try to pre-emptively send an

```
{
    messageType: UNREGISTER,
    from: Client1
    to: server|null,
    data: {}
 }
```

so that your server can remove it before the exception occurs.  This would also let you handle Offline messages, if that's something you're interested in.

Comment: I've modified the structure and now I use the handlers to take care of register and typing but when I try to catch that exception I get the same output  with or without that catch statement. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The exception happens because the server attempts to send data to the client socket which has been closed, there is no way to get rid of that exception, there is only handling it.  1) If you get that exception, it's not necessarily a bad thing, you should remove the client that threw it from the list 2) Are you sending an UNREGISTER message from the client when it shuts down so that the server can remove the client from `allClientsConnected`?

Comment: Now when I try to remove a client that disconnected I get this error:
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: I just sort it out. Everything works all right but I got one more question, considering that when I create a new client object it also start a thread, how could I possibly close it when the client decides to leave the chat?

Comment: Really depends on how you're doing it, but in your ClientThread you probably want to have a disconnected() method that sets a flag and allows the thread to end gracefully, since I assume the thread is just looping over while waiting for data to come in?